# Member of or in clause/ With clause vs collections / collections with bind variables or not

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle10g

I'm trying to optimize a big query (**with no sub-queries but huge table size**) in Oracle PL/ SQL (10g). To start, I removed few tables from the join and cached the data they were returning in collections (nested tables to be specific), which lead to two choices

**Example:**
(say the variable name is cache) and the condition in the original query was

```
where a.col_in_a = b.col_in_b;

so I changed it to,
select b.col_in_b bulk collect into cache from b where -- some conditions;
```

option 1

```
where a.col_in_a member of cache;
```

option 2

```
where a.col_in_b in (select column_value from table(cache));
```

**Question1: which of the above two is better.**

Going further, I also had a choice of not using collections and simply use a with clause with materialize hint

```
with cache as (SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
col_in_b from b where -- some condtions
)
select col_in_a from a,b where a.col_in_b = cache.col_in_b;
```

**Question 2 use collections or with clause to cache**

Once I take this decision, I would like to make this new query a little flexible, i.e. make it dynamic with few tables and conditions changing little bit here and there. This leads me to two more options
1. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'big select query'
2. OPEN-WITH-FOR 'big select query'

Since, I'm storing the result of this big query in a ref cursor, I believe OPEN-WITH-FOR is the way to go. Which leads me to writing the dynamic query in two ways

**Question 3: How to make something like below work in the ways metioned in question 1 and which is the best?**
`open cursor for 'select col_in_a from a,b where a.col_in_b in :cache'` using dummyCache
where dummyCache can be a comma separated list of strings OR can I pass a nested table using a bind variable and use a member of clause.. I'm not sure how to make this work..

I hope I've tried to explain clearly. Request all the folks to suggest me some better way as well..

Comment: Have you benchmarked the two collection approaches and the CTE (with-clause) approach, with and without the materialize hint? And comapred to the original query? Seems like you can answer 1 and 2 yourself really. I'd expect the CTE to perform better than the collection; whether either is better than the original depends on what the rest of the query is doing, though it seems like you're trying to outsmart the optimizer. But why not just check?

Comment: The materialize hint isn't documented, so I would be wary of using it in production code. Plus, I once had an ora-600 due to it, so I'm even more wary about it! I'd skip the hint and let Oracle decide whether it is worth materializing it; for example, if the subquery is used in multiple places within the overall query, then it is more than likely to be materialized anyway. Also, why nested tables and not Global Temporary Tables (GTTs)?

Comment: Hey Alex, with CTE the cost of the query is showing more. So I'm confused about the behavior. Can you suggest how do I benchmark and validate performance in these different scenarios

Comment: Hey Boneist, thanks for the tip. Also, The data I'm caching in nested tables is only used in this select query. In fact, this entire query is in a function that has only select statements. Does GTT make sense in this case?